DynDNS for VPN: Disable delivery of login page for the web on FRITZ!Box
I want to access my home network from the internet using WireGuard. My router, a FRITZ!Box, has it built-in, so its easy to activate. As I do not have a fixed IP, I use my domain and dynDNS; sending the dynDNS update is built-in into the router as well.
Connecting to the VPN via my domain works fine. However, the router exposes its login-page under the domain. I do not have any users with enabled login option for connections from the internet, so it is not a big problem. Still, I do not want this site to be seen. I would prefer some blank page or better: No response at all. But I can't find an option for that.
So my question is: How can I disable the login-page for the web?

I guess i'd be looking to use the firewall to allow connections to the management pages to only selected internal systems. I don't know much about how Fritzboxes do things, but most more-than-consumer-grade routers treat services they offer as universal across all interfaces they support, so when VPN traffic terminates on the router, it makes sense that it would have access to all the services on the router. On my router (edgeOS) I'd put a firewall ruleset on the 'vtun0' interface in the direction 'local', and block traffic to 80/443 there, since I can isolate the VPN to a specific interface.
